# Setting relative paths to temporary files in ModelBuilder using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have create a model in modelbuilder using ArcGIS where everything works on my PC but whenever I try run it on a different PC issues arise due to the model trying to save the temporary files to my PC. Please note that the model is set to use "relative paths".

How do I get the model to also use relative paths for temporary files so that the model can run on other PC's?